# "Vicino" vs "vicino a"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, adverbs

I always knew that the adverb "vicino" was followed by "a" - "vicino a casa". 
Now I have seen in a book "vicino Volterra". Is this correct? Perhaps both are correct?

Answer (score 7):

According to Treccani the use of “vicino” without the preposition “a” is incorrect though common:

***[VICINO O VICINO A](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/vicino-o-vicino-a_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)?***

> Con funzione di locuzione ➔preposizionale, ***è consigliabile evitare l’uso del solo vicino e preferire la forma con la preposizione a***
>
> vicino a Napoli
>
> vicino a scuola
>
> vicino a casa
>
> ***L’uso di vicino senza preposizione è dunque scorretto, anche se risulta abbastanza comune e diffuso da tempo***
>
> in un appartamento di Riano, vicino Roma («La Repubblica»).

Also the [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/vicino-roma-vicino-roma) agrees  with the above rule:

> Quel che è certo è che non si può usare il solo vicino con funzione di locuzione preposizionale: sono da evitare, benché alquanto diffusi persino nei giornali, vicino Roma, vicino casa (recte: «vicino a Roma», «vicino a casa»).»

Comment: Siccome l'OP ha posto la domanda in inglese, potresti aggiungere una traduzione in questa lingua?